# You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders (upgrading Monaco Editor)

Tags: webpack, babeljs, monaco-editor, babel-loader, react-app-rewired

I wanted to upgrade the version of Monaco Editor to v0.31.1. I did `npm install monaco-editor@0.31.1`, and the recompilation by `sudo PORT=8000 HTTPS=true ./node_modules/.bin/react-app-rewired start` gave me the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/monaco.contribution.js 154:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (154:11)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     dispose() {
|       onLanguageListener.dispose();
>       mode?.dispose();
|       mode = void 0;
|     }
```

Could anyone help?

**Edit 1:**
`package.json` before the upgrading:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.33.0",
    "@handsontable/react": "^9.0.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.8",
    "@microsoft/office-js-helpers": "^1.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/react-stripe-elements": "^6.0.4",
    "@uifabric/react-cards": "^0.109.49",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "color": "^3.1.2",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
    "cross-storage": "^1.0.0",
    "dva": "^2.4.1",
    "dva-model-creator": "^0.4.3",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "handsontable": "^9.0.2",
    "highcharts": "^7.0.3",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.20.0",
    "monaco-languageclient": "^0.13.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-core": "^11.0.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.105.4",
    "query-string": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-meta-tags": "^1.0.1",
    "react-monaco-editor": "^0.35.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "yup": "^0.28.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3000 react-app-rewired start",
    "start:https": "HTTPS=true  react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8096 build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/color": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/cross-storage": "^0.8.29",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.5",
    "@types/office-js": "^1.0.92",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/yup": "^0.26.33",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

When `"monaco-editor": "^0.20.0"`, `npm list monaco-editor` returns

```
$ npm list monaco-editor
npm list monaco-editor
frontend@0.1.0 /frontend
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY monaco-editor@0.20.0 
└─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY react-monaco-editor@0.35.0
  └── UNMET DEPENDENCY monaco-editor@0.20.0 

npm ERR! missing: monaco-editor@0.20.0, required by frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! missing: react-monaco-editor@0.35.0, required by frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! missing: monaco-editor@0.20.0, required by react-monaco-editor@0.35.0
```

When `"monaco-editor": "^0.31.1"`, `npm list monaco-editor` returns

```
$ npm list monaco-editor
frontend@0.1.0 /frontend
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY monaco-editor@0.31.1 
└─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY react-monaco-editor@0.35.0
  └── UNMET DEPENDENCY monaco-editor@0.31.1 

npm ERR! missing: monaco-editor@0.31.1, required by frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! missing: react-monaco-editor@0.35.0, required by frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! missing: monaco-editor@0.31.1, required by react-monaco-editor@0.35.0
```

**Edit 2:**

Following the anwser of @Bart, I installed `@babel/preset-env` by `yarn add @babel/preset-env --dev` and created `babel.config.json` with `{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]}`, but `react-app-rewired start` gave the same error.

Then, I realized that I do have a file `config-overrides.js`, the content is as follows:

```js
module.exports = function override (config, env) { 
    // disable chunks so the index.html won't change during development 
    config.optimization.splitChunks = {
        cacheGroups: {
            default: false,
        },
    };
    config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
    return config;
}
```

I then added the part for `config.module.rules`, but the compilation returned the same error.

**Additionally, it seems that the project can be built with `yarn build` without this error.** But building the project takes time.

```js
module.exports = function override (config, env) {
    config.module.rules = 
        [
          {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
              }
            }
          }
        ]
    
    // disable chunks so the index.html won't change during development 
    config.optimization.splitChunks = {
        cacheGroups: {
            default: false,
        },
    };
    config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
    return config;
}
```

Comment: Probably update Babel as well. Looks like the version you have doesn’t support <https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/>.

Comment: Which version are you updating from? I'm curious as I have similar issues and would like to get to a working version.

Comment: @Safiyya How could I check the version of babel in my mac OS?

Comment: You can use ` npm list monaco-editor` or ` npm list babel`, which version of the editor was working for you?

Comment: @Safiyya `"monaco-editor": "^0.20.0"` worked for me.

Comment: @Safiyya I added results of `npm list monaco-editor` to OP. `npm list babel` returns no useful information.

Answer (score 11):

The problem seems to be with the optional chaining syntax (the `?.` in `mode?.dispose();`). This is also listed as a breaking change in the [changelog](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#0310-10122021) of Monaco:

> the generated code is now bundled with ESBuild and the generated code makes use of newer browser features, e.g. optional chaining. These features should be available in all browsers, but they might not be parsed correctly by older JS parsers, specifically parcel v1 might have problems parsing the JS.

This syntax can be handled well by the [correct Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining). In general, it’s better to use `@babel/preset-env` instead of separate plugins. This preset takes care of several plugins at once. Do you have a babel config file where you could include this preset? This can be as simple as installing `@babel/preset-env` as a dev dependency, and creating a `babel.config.json` file in your project root with the following contents:

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Secondly, it could mean that your Babel config is already working correctly, but that anything inside `node_modules` is ignored by Webpack (used under the hood by Create React App), as is often done to speed up transpilation times. Then you’ll have to find a way to overrule the Webpack config so that your `monaco` dependency is not skipped for transpilation.

I see you’re already using `react-app-rewired`, so updating the Webpack config is done as explained in [their documentation](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#extended-configuration-options):

```js
// config-overrides.js
module.exports = function override (config, env) { 
    // disable chunks so the index.html won't change during development 
    config.optimization.splitChunks = {
        cacheGroups: {
            default: false,
        },
    };
    config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
    
    config.module.rules = [
      {
        test: /node_modules\/monaco-editor/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          // if you include your babel config here,
          // you don’t need the `babel.config.json` file
          options: { presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] }
        }
      },
      ...config.module.rules
    ]
    return config;
}
```

Integrating Babel can be done via `babel-loader`, see instructions [here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/).

Comment: Thank you... I installed `@babel/preset-env` by `yarn add @babel/preset-env --dev` and created a `babel.config.json` with your content, but the compilation gave the same error. For your second point, I don't know what to do...

Comment: Added some more pointers for your help

Comment: Thank you. I added `Edit 2` to OP. Could you help?

Comment: Are you sure the part you added for `config.module.rules` is correct? The webpack documentation that I linked provides an example where `node_modules` is excluded, as is most common. But here we’re trying to do the opposite. I updated my answer with an example `config-overrides.js` (maybe the `test` regex is not perfect, but you get the idea)

Comment: I'm not sure, i was wondering that too. Could you propose a precise modification?

Comment: I commented `exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,` in my code, i still had the same error.

Comment: It could be that another loader (see `...config.module?.rules` above) doesn’t understand the `?.` syntax. I updated the order of the rules in my example above — `babel-loader` should go first.

Comment: Thank you for this... But could you work directly on my `config-overrides.js`? My knowledge of webpack and react-app-rewired does not allow me to adapt your answer to my code.

Comment: I see your update, I run it, still the same error. But I just realized that, no matter what wrong text I put in `config-overrides.js`, we still first see `mode?.dispose();` error. It seems that `config-overrides.js` did not play its role.

Comment: Is the file in your repository root? You can double-check if it’s used at all by placing a `console.log` or `throw new Error()` somewhere in the file

Comment: I realized that `sudo PORT=8000 HTTPS=true ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start` ignored `config-overrides.js`. I should use `sudo PORT=8000 HTTPS=true ./node_modules/.bin/react-app-rewired start`. But with your `config-overfides.js` I had the same error.

Comment: The `build` command seems to work, and is run via `react-scripts`. Would it be an option to run `start` via `react-scripts` as well?

Comment: Did this help fix your issue?

Comment: Hello, you did help, but I could not make this answer work. At the moment, I used the workaround described in my answer. I will not select your answer, but I will give you the bounty for the help.

Comment: I solved this issue by installing a specific version of the *monaco-editor*
`"@monaco-editor/react": "^4.3.1"` ---> `"4.4.6"`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with my project. There is a monaco-editor-webpack-plugin that handles these loader issues. But the latest version has some problems in it.
So I installed `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin@6.0.0` along with `monaco-editor@0.30.1`. Then you just have to add the plugin to webpack.

```js
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new MonacoWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as you in my Vue project.

Maybe you can handle it like this:

Download the source code of monaco-editor from GitHub

Modify the function `buildESM` and the function `buildOneAMD` in file `monaco-editor/build/utils.js`

eg: set `target` to `es2015`

```js
function buildESM(options) {
    build({
        entryPoints: options.entryPoints,
        bundle: true,
        target: 'es2015',
        format: 'esm',
        define: {
            AMD: 'false'
        },
        banner: {
            js: bundledFileHeader
        },
        external: options.external,
        outbase: `src/${options.base}`,
        outdir: `out/release/${options.base}/esm/`,
        plugins: [
            alias({
                'vscode-nls': path.join(__dirname, 'fillers/vscode-nls.ts')
            })
        ]
    });
}
```

and then, `npm run release` and wait until it's done

```sh
npm run release
```

you get the folder `monaco-editor/release`, copy the contents of the folder `release` and paste into the folder `modules/monaco-editor` you created under your project.

in your project, modify the `package.json`, set `monaco-editor` to `file:modules/monaco-editor`, and `npm install`

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "monaco-editor": "file:modules/monaco-editor",
  }
}
```

```sh
npm install
```

It's my way to solve this problem above, if somebody find the better solution, please reply to me here.

Excuse me, my English is bad.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that you recompiled Monaco Editor yourself.

Comment: I solved this issue by installing a specific version of the *monaco-editor*
`"@monaco-editor/react": "^4.3.1"` ---> `"4.4.6"`

Answer (score 1):

We have found two temporary solutions:

The first solution is, by following [this thread](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/881#issuecomment-858346012), to use the follows in `package.json`:

```json
"browserslist":[
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
]
```

The second solution is, to use `import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api'` rather than `import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'`.

These two solutions bypass the error of optional chaining syntax. We have not found a direct way to deal with babel, babel-loder, react-app-rewired, etc.

Comment: Thank you! The 2nd solution (explicit import) worked.